# Nerve cell vs neural cell

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Why do people use *nerve cell* when both *nerve* and *cell* are nouns? Shouldn't the first word be an adjective like in *neural cell*?

If *nerve cell* is valid, is there a subtle difference between *nerve cell* and *neural cell*? *Neural* means "relating to a nerve" ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neural)), so is the difference that one is actually a nerve, and the other only relating to a nerve?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to use nouns as adjectives: *door frame, carpet tack, ceiling tile, car seat...*

Comment: I've made this into what may be a better question for this site. @Yordan If you're learning English and want to know about attributive nouns, then do consider joining [ELL.SE] as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns are frequently used to modify other nouns, especially in cases where the modifier indicates a location. When the noun is shorter (easier to say) or more familiar than the adjective, it makes this usage more likely to occur.

For example: people are more likely to say "back pain" than "dorsal pain," or "car trouble" instead of "automotive trouble."